# Which library/module is best and should i use for multiple file upload from a form if i am using react in frontend and Spring boot in backend?

Tags: java, reactjs, hibernate, spring-boot, react-redux

Since choosing a library is a respnsible activity. It should be scalable and also robust. I have come across mutler and react-upload-file module suggestions. I am not sure which module is the best one to use. And how exactly does file upload work conceptually. 
I couldn't find an article which could explain me step by step what happens behind the scene when we want to save the uploaded file in containers like S3 bucket. 
Could some please also refer me some article.

Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

https://www.dropzonejs.com/

[Dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) is open source and highly customizable. It is also easy to use provides nice 'drag N drop' interface.